# java how to compute

Tags: java, swing, oop, methods, jframe

How can I compute for the balance? I want to subtract withdrawn amount to the saved entered amount of the user.

Here's my code:

AccountInformation.java

```
    public class AccountInformation
{
    private int acct_no;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String bday;;

    public void setAcct_No(int an)
    {
        this.acct_no = an;
    }
    public void setName(String n)
    {
        this.name = n;
    }
    public void setAddress(String ad)
    {
        this.address = ad;
    }
    public void setBday(String bd)
    {
        this.bday = bd;
    }

    public int getAcct_No()
    {
        return this.acct_no;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getAddress()
    {
        return this.address;
    }
    public String getBday()
    {
        return this.bday;
    }
}
```

SavingsAccount.java

```
    import javax.swing.*;
public class SavingsAccount extends AccountInformation
{   
    private int withdraw;
    private int balance;
    private int amount;

    public void setAmount(int am)
    {
        this.amount = am;
    }   
    public void setWithdraw(int w)
    {
        this.withdraw = w;
    }
    public void setBalance(int b)
    {
        this.balance = b;
    }

    public int getAmount()
    {
        return this.amount;
    }   
    public int getWithdraw()
    {
        return this.withdraw;
    }   
    public int getBalance()
    {
        return this.balance = amount - withdraw;
    }
}
```

CheckingAccount.java

```
    import javax.swing.*;

public class CheckingAccount extends AccountInformation
{
    private int issue_date;

    public void setIssue_Date(int id)
    {
        this.issue_date = id;
    }

    public int getIssue_Date()
    {
        return this.issue_date;
    }
}
```

BankAccount.java

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BankAccount extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JLabel acct_noL, nameL, addressL, bdayL, amountL;
    private JTextField acct_noTF, nameTF, addressTF, bdayTF, amountTF;
    private JButton addB, checkB, clearB, exitB;

    SavingsAccount[] savings = new SavingsAccount[10];

    private int index = 0;
    private int acct_no = 1000;

    public BankAccount()
    {
        for(int ctr=0;ctr<=9;ctr++)
        {
            savings[ctr] = new SavingsAccount();
        }
        setTitle("Bank Account");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        acct_noL = new JLabel("Account Number",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        nameL = new JLabel("Name",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        addressL = new JLabel("Address",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        bdayL = new JLabel("Birthday",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        amountL = new JLabel("Amount to Deposit",SwingConstants.RIGHT);

        acct_noTF = new JTextField(10);
        nameTF = new JTextField(10);
        addressTF = new JTextField(10);
        bdayTF = new JTextField(10);
        amountTF = new JTextField(10);

        acct_noTF.setText("1000");

        addB = new JButton("Add");
        checkB = new JButton("Check Balance");
        clearB = new JButton("Clear");
        exitB = new JButton("Exit");

        addB.addActionListener(this);
        checkB.addActionListener(this);
        clearB.addActionListener(this);
        exitB.addActionListener(this);

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,2));
        pane.add(acct_noL);
        pane.add(acct_noTF);
        pane.add(nameL);
        pane.add(nameTF);
        pane.add(addressL);
        pane.add(addressTF);
        pane.add(bdayL);
        pane.add(bdayTF);
        pane.add(amountL);
        pane.add(amountTF);
        pane.add(addB);
        pane.add(checkB);
        pane.add(clearB);
        pane.add(exitB);
    }

    private String showAccountInfo(int an)
    {
        String info="";

        for(int s=0;s<=9;s++)
        {
            if(savings[s].getAcct_No()==an)
            {
                info = "Account Number: " + savings[s].getAcct_No() + "\nName: " + savings[s]. getName() +
                         "\nAddress: " + savings[s].getAddress() + "\nBirthday " + savings[s].getBday() + 
                         "\nBalance: " + savings[s].getAmount();
            }
        }
        return info;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        int inputAcct_No;
        int ewithdraw;
        int eissue_date;

        if(source==addB)
        {
            if(index<=9)
            {
                savings[index].setAcct_No(acct_no);
                savings[index].setName(nameTF.getText());
                savings[index].setAddress(addressTF.getText());
                savings[index].setBday(bdayTF.getText());
                savings[index].setAmount(Integer.parseInt(amountTF.getText()));
                index++;
                acct_no++;
                acct_noTF.setText(""+acct_no);
                nameTF.setText(null);
                addressTF.setText(null);
                bdayTF.setText(null);
                amountTF.setText(null);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bank Account Saved!");
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bank Accounts are Full!");
            }
        }

        if(source==checkB)
        {
            SavingsAccount savings = new SavingsAccount();
            CheckingAccount checking = new CheckingAccount();
            inputAcct_No = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Account Number"));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,this.showAccountInfo(inputAcct_No));
            int confirm_withdraw = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Would you like to withdraw?");
            if(confirm_withdraw==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
            savings.setWithdraw(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amount to be withdrawn")));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your balance is: " + (savings.getBalance()));
            int confirm_issue_date = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Would you like to issue cheque?");
            if(confirm_issue_date==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                String Receiver = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter name of the receiver");
                checking.setIssue_Date(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amount to be issued")));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cheque is issued to " + Receiver + " with the amount of " +checking.getIssue_Date() + 
                                                                "\nYour balance is: " + (savings.getBalance()-checking.getIssue_Date()));
            }
            }
            else if(confirm_withdraw==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
            {
            }
            else if(confirm_withdraw==JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
            {
            }
        }

        if(source==clearB)
        {
            nameTF.setText(null);
            addressTF.setText(null);
            bdayTF.setText(null);
            amountTF.setText(null);
        }

        if(source==exitB)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BankAccount ba = new BankAccount();
        ba.setSize(500,400);
        ba.setVisible(true);
        ba.setResizable(false);
        ba.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you specify which part of code you are having problem? nobody have time to revise every single line of your code!

Comment: its our homework.. i just cant find where the problem is.. dont know how could i compute for the remaining balance if i will enter amount in the withdraw input dialog

Answer (score 1):

> "*I want to subtract withdrawn amount to the saved entered amount of the user."*

Here's is your `withdraw` code

```
public void setWithdraw(int w)
{
    this.withdraw = w;
}
```

There is no need to even have a `withdraw` field to set, unless you want a list of transactions or something, which you don't have. So take out the `withdraw` field from the class. It doesn't need to be set. And just do something like this

```
public void withdraw(int amount)
{
   balance -= amount;
}
```

All you need to do is subtract the amount from the balance. Do the same with your deposits (If you decide to add a deposit method. After all, what's an account if you can't deposit).

---

**EDIT**

Also you're creating a new Account every time `actionPerformed` is called

```
SavingsAccount Savings = new SavingsAccount();
CheckingAccount checking = new CheckingAccount();
```

Don'r do that. That's why the widthraw amount is always the same as the balance. Instead put them as class member. And remove the above code from the `actionPerformed`

---

**UPDATE**

Try running this *very* simple program. You will see how withdrawing should work

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class AccountTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account = new Account(1000.00);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Amount to withdraw: ");
        double amountToWithdraw = scanner.nextDouble();

        account.withDraw(amountToWithdraw);

        System.out.println("You balance is now " + account.getBalance());
    }
}

class Account{
    double balance;

    public Account(double initialBalance) {
        balance = initialBalance;
    }

    public double getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }

    public void withDraw(double amount) {
        balance -= amount;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Here's a suggestion. I see you have a SavingsAccount array. So you probably want multiple accounts. I also you that you're trying to access a specific account by account id in the actionPerformed if the checkB is pressed. What you should do then, if loop through the array and if the id is found, then use that account to do your work. Something like this

```
inputAcct_No = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Account Number"));
SavingsAccount savings;
for (SavingsAccount account : SavingsAccounts){  <-- your array
    if (acound.getId() == inputAcct_No){
        savings = account;
    }
}
// do something with savings
```

Now you can do something with that account because it is referencing the account in the array.

Comment: thanks.. but the outcome is still what i've entered in the withdraw..

Comment: What are you _trying to get? Maybe you want to get balance instead of getAmount or getWithdraw. Not sure what you're trying to do. It doesn't seem that difficult. You just need to examine for yourself exactly what you're trying to do then compare the logic to your code.

Comment: if i enter an amount i  the withdraw.. there should be a message dialog box that states the remaining balance.. but the balance the shows is just the amount i entered in the withdraw.. it did not compute...

Comment: you're probably using `getWithrdaw` or `getAmount` when you should be using `getBalance`

Comment: im having a problem in the `if(source==checkB)` part.. in displaying the balance when you entered amount in the withdraw.. and also for the cheque..

Comment: See the second part of my answer.

Comment: if i remove them.. i encounter error..

Comment: If you put them as class member, you won't

Comment: You need _really_ need to narrow down your code to a specific problem. No one wants to swim through your code to try and figure out what you're trying to do. And ask a better more precise problem. Something you didn't do in your post.

Comment: Is this part of my code is right? ..`"\nYour balance is: " + checking.getBalance());`

Comment: from this `public int getBalance()
{
    return this.balance = savings.getBalance() - getIssue_Date();
}`

Comment: Why do you even have a `SavingsAccount` inside you `CheckingAccount`. And `getBalance` should only `return `balance`

Comment: it was in the given problem -_-.. we should be able to apply inheritance of accouninformation to savingsaccount and checkingaccount .. and what i did was my understanding in our homework..

Comment: Yes the inheritance part seems right, but think about in terms of object. a checkings account is an object. a savings account is an object. In real world terms, does a checking account ever _have_ a savings account? No. They're two totally separate entities.

Comment: Take a look at my update. Maybe you'll pick something up from it.

Comment: :(  i just can't still get it ..

Comment: checking account should have the issuing of cheque...

Comment: Here's a suggestion. I see you have a `SavingsAccount` array. So you probably want multiple accounts. I also you that you're trying to access a specific account by account id in the actionPerformed if the `checkB` is pressed. What you should do then, if loop through the array and if the id is found, _then_ use that account to do your work.

Comment: Take a look at my last edit. Maybe you want something like that.

Comment: in my revised code.. what i needed is the exact and right method to be used in the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your balance is: " + **(savings.getBalance())**); could you tell me what is the right code i can use to that specific line??? please...

Answer (score 0):

Its better to tell the exact issue you are facing , its difficult to check the complete code..

At a galance what i got is that in your **SavingsAccount** class getBalance() method you are simply subtracting and returning but there is no effect on the actual value of **balance**.

What i think you have to do balance-withdraw in your setWithdraw() method.